# ALL() isn't working to "remove a filter" in DAX; relationship issue?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Basic premise:

- 'Orders' are comprised of items from multiple 'Zones'.
- Customers can call in for 'Credits' (refunds) on botched 'Orders'.
- There is a true many-to-many relationship here, because one order could have multiple credits called in at different times; similarly, a customer can call in once regarding multiple orders (generating only one credit memo).
- 'Credits' granularity is at the item level, i.e.

  ```
  CREDIT  |   SO      |   ITEM    |   ZONE    |   CREDAMT
  -------------------------------------------------------
  42      |   1       |   56      |   A       |   $6
  42      |   1       |   52      |   A       |   $8
  42      |   1       |   62      |   B       |   $20
  42      |   2       |   56      |   A       |   $12
  ```
- 'Order Details' granularity is at the zone level, i.e.

  ```
  SO      |   ZONE    |   DOL_AMT
  -------------------------------
  1       |   A       |   $50
  1       |   B       |   $20
  1       |   C       |   $100
  2       |   A       |   $26
  ```
- I have a 'Zone' filter table that helps me sort things better and roll up into broader categories, i.e.

  ```
  ZONE    |   TEMP    |   SORT
  -------------------------------
  A       |   DRY     |   2
  B       |   COLD    |   3
  C       |   DRY     |   1
  ```

What I need:

- I want a pair of visuals for a side by side comparison of order total by zone next to credit total by zone.

What's working:

- The 'Credits' component is easy, `CreditTotal = abs(sumx(Credits,Credits[CREDAMT]))` with Zone as a legend item.
- I have a ORDER component that works *when the zone is in the credit memo*

  ```
  Order $ by Zone =
  CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Order Details'[DOL_AMT] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Order Details'[SO], Credits[SO] ),
    ALL ( Credits[CreditCategory] )
  )
  ```

My issue:

- Zones that *didn't* have a credit against them won't show up. So instead of

  ```
  CREDIT  |   ZONE    |   ORDER $ BY ZONE
  ----------------------------------
  42      |   A       |   $76
  42      |   B       |   $20
  42      |   C       |   $100
  ```

  I get

  ```
  CREDIT  |   ZONE    |   ORDER $ BY ZONE
  ----------------------------------
  42      |   A       |   $76
  42      |   B       |   $20
  ```

I have tried to remove this filter by tacking on `ALL(Zones[Zone])` and/or `ALL('Order Details'[Zone])`, but it doesn't help, presumably because it *is* reporting "all zones" actually found in the 'Credits' table. **I'm hoping there's some way to ask it to report all zones in the 'Order Details' table based upon SOs in the 'Credits' table.**

In case it helps, here's how the relationships are structured; as an aside, I've tried mixing and matching various combinations of active/inactive, single vs. bidirectional filtering, etc., but the current configuration is the only one that seems to remotely work as desired.
[image: Relationships in data model]

I'm grateful for any suggestions; please let me know if anything is unclear. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `ALL(Credits[Zone])`?

Comment: @Alexis No dice, unfortunately. :( Adding this has no change on the output. Thank you for the suggestion, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by using `'Order Details'[Zone]` rather than `Zones[Zone]` in the table visual and this measure:

```
Order $ by Zone = 
CALCULATE (
  SUM ( 'Order Details'[DOL_AMT] ),
  USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Order Details'[SO], Credits[SO] )
)
```

---

Notice that regardless of your measure, there is no row in `Credits` corresponding to zone `C`, so it doesn't know what to put in the `CREDIT` column unless you tell it exactly how.

If you remove the `CREDIT` dimension column, then you don't need to swap tables as I suggested above. You can just use the measure above and then write a new *measure* for the `CREDIT` column instead:

```
CreditValue =
CALCULATE(
    VALUES(Credits[CREDIT]),
    ALL(Credits),
    Credits[SO] IN VALUES('Order Details'[SO])
)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me wrap my head around this. I guess my takeaway is... the zones corresponding to an `Order Details[SO]` will always exist, whether or not they have an associated entry in `Credits[SO]`. When I base the calculation around those in `Credits`, I lose out on unmatched zones in `Order Details`. I know you've helped me before, too, so I just wanted to say thanks again!! :)